# make a query with ORM and use (AND) and (OR) inside together

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I want to make a query with ORM and use (AND) and (OR) inside together
My code is :

```
$users = \App\User::where('type',1)->orWhere('type',2)->orWhere('type',3)->where('name',$name)->where('family',$family)->get();
```

That is False

my code should join

```
$users = \App\User::where('type',1)->orWhere('type',2)->orWhere('type',3)->get();
```

with

```
 $users = \App\User::where('name',$name)->where('family',$family)->get()
```

how can I write true Query ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the case is with the same field so you need to go with `whereIn` As @Tharaka Dilshan had mentioned.

If the case is more complicated than this, you may want to go with grouped queries :

```
$users = \App\User::where(function ($query) {
    $query->where('type', 1)->orWhere('type', 2)->orWhere('type', 3);
})
->where('name', $name)
->where('family', $family)
->get();
```

For more details about [*Parameter Grouping.*](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#parameter-grouping)

Comment: Thanks . now I want to join This with Other Tables . What should I do ?

Comment: You may find the right reference in here [eloquent-relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are looking for is `whereIn()` function.

`whereIn()` function compare a single columns values with an `array` of data.

```
$users = \App\User::where([
    ['name',$name],
    ['family', $family]
])
->whereIn('type', [1,2,3])
->get()
```